# DRF explicit ordering direction

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Im looking for a solution for DRF where I would get query like this:

```
..../?sort=foo&order=asc/desc
```

I was able to change order param to "**sort**" but I dont know how to add explicitly "**&order=asc**" except current solution which uses "**-**" before column.

thank you in advance.

Comment: from your question I am guessing that you are using a custom list function in the viewset.  Please add the complete viewset or view class so that we can suggest a solution.

Comment: Its not about the way my viewset is made. Its about how DRF works with sorting.
I need som plugin or custom orderingFilter.